# Parse strings that are surrounded with quotes

Tags: json, string, haskell

I'm parsing some data I don't control. I have values that are an array of strings. They can either be normal strings, a string representation of a number, or a number with quotes around it.

```
["This is just a string", "\"5\"", "3"]
```

I would like to write a function `toValue` that converts them into the appropriate type to be converted to JSON.

```
toValue :: (ToJSON a) => String -> a
toValue (if a number) = parseInt
toValue (if a quoted number) = parseInt . stripQuotes
toValue _ = id
```

I would like to strip the quotes if it is a number surrounded by quotes, then convert it to a number if a number, otherwise pass it back as a string.

Can I do this with pattern matching? Some other way?

Comment: use `isNumber` from `Data.Char` module, and use `digitToInt` to convert it to `Char`.

Comment: The type of `toValue` is claiming that it will convert a string to every type in the `ToJSON` class. This is not want you want. You could use existentials, but these are not what you want either AFACIS. Maybe you want `toValue :: String -> Value` (where `Value` is the one in `Data.Aeson`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    import Data.Char
    import Data.Bool

    parse a@('"':n:'"':[]) = bool (Left a) (Right (read [n] :: Int)) (isNumber n)
    parse a@('"':n:m:'"':[]) = bool (Left a) (Right (read [n,n] :: Int)) (isNumber n && isNumber m)
    parse a@(n:[]) = bool (Left a) (Right (read [n] :: Int)) (isNumber n)
    parse a@(n:m:[]) = bool (Left a) (Right (read [n,n] :: Int)) (isNumber n && isNumber m)
    parse xs = Left xs

> map parse ["This is just a string", "\"5\"", "3"]
[Left "This is just a string",Right 5,Right 3]
```

then, you can use `either` function from `Data.Either` module to encode number (Rights) and string (Lefts) to JSON.

Answer (score -1):

Writing a function `toValue :: ToJSON a => String -> a` as you are proposing is not so hard: let us simply make `toValue` a method of the class `ToJSON`

```
class ToJSON a where
  toValue :: String -> a
```

and then define the instance for `Int` as

```
instance ToJSON Int where
  toValue s@('\"' : _) = read (read s) -- with quotes
  toValue s            = read s        -- without quotes
```

The instance for `String` is slightly more involved (as `String` is a synonym for `[Char]`) but by no means rocket science:

```
class ToJSONList a where
  toValues :: String -> [a]

instance ToJSONList Char where
  toValues = id

instance ToJSONList a => ToJSON [a] where
  toValue = toValues
```

Now, testing it in an interactive session, we have:

```
> toValue "This is just a string" :: String
"This is just a string"

> toValue "\"5\"" :: Int
5

> toValue "3" :: Int
3
```

However, from your question it seems that you have a use case that is not well supported by such a function `toValue`, i.e., to convert all elements of a list to their appropriate JSON-representation. To do so, you probably want to introduce an algebraic datatype for representing JSON-values:

```
data JSON = JInt Int | JString String deriving Show
```

and then have function toJSON that takes strings to their most appropriate JSON-representation:

```
toJSON :: String -> JSON
toJSON    s      =
  case reads s of
    [(n, "")] -> JInt n                                   -- Int, no quotes                         
    _         -> case reads s of
                   [(s, "")] -> case reads s of
                                  [(n, "")] -> JInt n     -- Int, quotes
                                  _         -> JString s  -- String, quotes
                   _         -> JString s                 -- String, no quotes
```

Indeed, to answer that part of your question, this function is defined just by (nested) pattern matching. However, if the (grammar of the) language you need to parse becomes more complicated then just integer literals, quoted integer literals, and string literals, this way of defining parsers quickly becomes to clumsy and error-prone, and you may want to start looking into [parser combinators](https://hackage.haskell.org/packages/#cat:Parsing) or [parser generators](http://www.haskell.org/happy/) then.

For your simple language of JSON values, this is arguably still fine though. Here is a simple example in an interactive session:

```
> map toJSON ["This is just a string", "\"5\"", "3"]
[JString "This is just a string",JInt 5,JInt 3]
```